# Convergence of the complex QR algorithm to Schur decomposition

Tags: algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, python, schur-decomposition

I study the complex Schur decomposition of a complex matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, that is:
$$ A = U T U^H $$
where $T$ is upper-triangular (the eigenvalues of $A$ appear on its diagonal, and may be complex) and $U$ is unitary $U^H = U^{-1}$ (recall that $U^H = U^* = \bar{U}^T $). Such a decomposition always exists.

The standard way to compute the Schur decomposition (at least, the one used in all the sources I found, including Golub & Van Loan 2013, "*Matrix Calculations*" and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)) is using the QR algorithm (see Golub & Van Loan, chapter 7, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm)). Basically, one repeats the following steps:

1. Set $T_0 = A$ and $U = I$ (in practice, one starts with reduction of $A$ to an Hessenberg form).
2. Compute the QR factorization $T_k = Q_k R_k$.
3. Form $T_{k+1} = R_k Q_K = Q_k^H Q_k R_k Q_k = Q_k^H T_k Q_k$.
4. Accumulate $U = U Q_k$.

Then, in most cases (and this is an issue I need clarifications about) $T_{k+1} \to T$ converges to the upper-triangular matrix $T$ of the Schur decomposition and $U = \lim_{k \to \infty} Q_0 Q_1 \cdots Q_k$.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77914/qr-algorithm-convergence-property) the poster quotes a theorem that ensure convergence: let $|\lambda_1| > ... > |\lambda_n | \ge 0$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Then
$$ (T_{k})_{i,j} = O\left(\left(\dfrac{\vert \lambda_{i} \vert}{\vert \lambda_{j} \vert}\right)^k\right)$$ for $i > j$.

This means that if there are $\lambda_{i_1}$ and $\lambda_{i_2}$ such that $|\lambda_{i_1}| = |\lambda_{i_2}|$, or they are very close, $\left| \frac{|\lambda_{i_1}|}{|\lambda_{i_2}|} - 1 \right| < \mathrm{tol}$ (here tol is the computer's numerical tolerance) the matrices $T_k$ will fail to converge to $0$ in the element $(T_k)_{i_1,i_2}$ and thus won't converge to an upper-triangular matrix.

I have written a code to implement the QR algorithm for complex matrices, and encountered this phenomena: a matrix that failed to convergence to upper-triangular with eigenvalues almost the same in their absolute value.

Python's SciPy package has a special function $\texttt{scipy.linalg.schur}$ that computes the Schur decomposition even for such bad matrices. I have three questions:

1. How to overcome this problem in the framework of the QR algorithm? Or is it impossible and I am forced to accept that for some matrices the QA algorithm just won't work?
2. What are the necessary and/or sufficient condition for the convergence of the QR algorithm to the Schur decomposition of $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$?
3. How Python's SciPy schur function (which uses LAPACK function at the back stage) overcome this problem and compute Schur decomposition even for such bad matrices?

Related Questions:

- [Can we make an algorithm for Schur Decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517255/can-we-make-an-algorithm-for-schur-decomposition)
- [Understanding the QR eigenvalue finding algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196559/understanding-the-qr-eigenvalue-finding-algorithm)
- [QR algorithm with reduced Hessenberg form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692439/qr-algorithm-with-reduced-hessenberg-form)
- [QR-algorithm - convergence property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77914/qr-algorithm-convergence-property)
- [Convergence of QR algorithm to upper triangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262363/convergence-of-qr-algorithm-to-upper-triangular-matrix)

Comment: This problem appears also for $\lambda(A) = \{0.62534345+0.61656135i, -0.25075095+0.07059212i,         0.07124168+0.01315155i,  0.2578328 -0.04137332i\}$ which satisfy $|\lambda|(A) = \{ 0.87818126, 0.26049815, 0.07244543, 0.2611312 \}$. We see $A$ has 2 eigenvalues close to each other $|\lambda| \approx 0.26$ but still not as close as $10^{-15}$.